# Ubuntu slows down Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Today I've installed Ubuntu for Desktop for the first time. And right away I noticed that when I installed it, Windows Explorer has been slowed down big time.

When switching to a different Windows account, which does not have Ubuntu installed, File Explorer works perfectly fine.

When deleting Ubuntu from the account that has Ubuntu, File Explorer works fine again, making it look like Ubuntu is the reason for a slow-down.

But, why? And, how to fix this?

Comment: A few items of information that would be helpful for troubleshooting -- First, does the issue appear if you install the Debian distribution into WSL?  If so, then we've definitely eliminated any Ubuntu cause here.  Also, it would be helpful if you could quantify "slowed down" - UI?  File operations?  Changing directories?  How long does an operation take with and without?  Thanks!

Comment: Does your Windows Task Manager show a lot of [init processes](https://superuser.com/questions/1529098/wsl-processes-consuming-my-cpu) when Ubuntu WSL is running?

Comment: As a heads-up, since your question was migrated from Ask Ubuntu to Super User, you can use the same Ask Ubuntu account to log in here.  That way, you'll get access to edit your question, reply to it, etc.  Don't create a separate account, since that account won't have access to this question.  Thanks!